# Google sheet API (with java) is showing "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.", "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I am using google sheet API to edit my google sheet on the drive. Link sharing is already on. But this is showing the following error:

Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}

My code is as follows:

> 

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.AppendValuesResponse;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.UpdateValuesResponse;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.ValueRange;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class SheetsQuickstart {
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Sheets API Java Quickstart";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

    /*
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);

    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport. 
     * @return An authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
     */
    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = SheetsQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();   
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    }

    /*
     * Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
     * https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
     */
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        final String spreadsheetId = "1KQy633356786cc22i0sCYFoD4h333oTl2Lk";//
        final String range = "Sheet_name!A2:B"; //I am intentionally not showing the name and also the link
        Sheets service = new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
        ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId, range).execute();
        List<List<Object>> values = Arrays.asList(
        Arrays.asList("Franklin",6897877));
        ValueRange body = new ValueRange()
                .setValues(values);
        AppendValuesResponse result =
                    service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId, range, body)
                            .setValueInputOption("USER_ENTERED").setInsertDataOption("INSERT_ROWS").setIncludeValuesInResponse(true)
                            .execute();
            System.out.printf("%d cells appended.", result.getUpdates().getUpdatedCells());
        List<List<Object>> value = response.getValues();
        if (values == null || values.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No data found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Name, ID");
            for (List row : value) {
                System.out.printf("%s, %s\n", row.get(0), row.get(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are using the code from the Sheets API [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java), I guess you first generated a token to read the Spreadsheet, which only requires the `SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS_READONLY` token and executed the example.

In order to update the scopes, you need to remove the token file saved in `TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH`, execute the code again and log in. Then Oauth2 will give you the new updated tokens.

Comment: Bro you save my day, I just unInstall application and install it again and it gives me new token